# how to save data fields to Firebase user input

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, user-input

i have been trying to save user inputed information to Firebase but my app has been stopped and crashing.i have created a class that will take the Getter method of the variables i have declared,i have tried to change how to save the value but nothing has proved to be working.
**MainActivity.java**

```
  }
    });
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DoctorReg();
        }
    });
    }

  private void DoctorReg()
  {
      String name=text.getText().toString().trim();
      String lname=text1.getText().toString().trim();
      String sex=s.getSelectedItem().toString();
      String username=text2.getText().toString().trim();
      String password=text3.getText().toString().trim();
      String email=text4.getText().toString().trim();
      String pnum=text5.getText().toString().trim();
      String padd=text6.getText().toString().trim();
      String province=s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
      String speciality=s2.getSelectedItem().toString();
      if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
      {
          String id=databaseReference.push().getKey();
          DoctorReg doctorReg= new DoctorReg(id,name,lname,sex,username,password,email,pnum,padd,province,speciality);
          databaseReference.child(id).setValue(doctorReg);
          Toast.makeText(this, "Patient is Added ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
      else
      {
          Toast.makeText(this, "You should Enter a Name ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }

  }
```

**DocRegistration.java**

```
public final class DoctorReg {
String Doctor_Id,F_Name,L_Name,Sex,Username_Doc,Password_Doc,Email_Doc,PNum_Doc,Postal_Address_Doc,Province_Doc,Speciality;
public DoctorReg(){}

public DoctorReg(String doctor_Id, String f_Name, String l_Name, String sex, String username_Doc, String password_Doc, String email_Doc, String PNum_Doc, String postal_Address_Doc, String province_Doc, String speciality) {
    this.Doctor_Id = doctor_Id;
    this.F_Name = f_Name;
    this.L_Name = l_Name;
    this.Sex = sex;
    this.Username_Doc = username_Doc;
    this.Password_Doc = password_Doc;
    Email_Doc = email_Doc;
    this.PNum_Doc = PNum_Doc;
    this.Postal_Address_Doc = postal_Address_Doc;
    this.Province_Doc = province_Doc;
    this.Speciality = speciality;
}

public String getDoctor_Id() {
    return Doctor_Id;
}

public String getF_Name() {
    return F_Name;
}

public String getL_Name() {
    return L_Name;
}

public String getSex() {
    return Sex;
}

public String getUsername_Doc() {
    return Username_Doc;
}

public String getPassword_Doc() {
    return Password_Doc;
}

public String getEmail_Doc() {
    return Email_Doc;
}

public String getPNum_Doc() {
    return PNum_Doc;
}

public String getPostal_Address_Doc() {
    return Postal_Address_Doc;
}

public String getProvince_Doc() {
    return Province_Doc;
}

public String getSpeciality() {
    return Speciality;
}
```

**LogCat**

```
04-13 22:27:26.356 7323-7323/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.remy_stolz.myapplication, PID: 7323
                                             com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: doctor_id
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zzhe(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzf(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzao(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzan(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)
                                                 at com.example.remy_stolz.myapplication.DocRegistrationActivity.DoctorReg(DocRegistrationActivity.java:120)
                                                 at com.example.remy_stolz.myapplication.DocRegistrationActivity$5.onClick(DocRegistrationActivity.java:99)
                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

04-13 22:27:26

Comment: pardon me if im wrong, my guess is that firebase is trying to create a new column which has the same name but different capitalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow proper naming conventions of java, this will help you now in this problem by solving the conflict and will avoid some other bugs too.Also

1. For classes, use `UpperCamelCase.`
2. For class members and local variables use `lowerCamelCase`
3. For packages, use reverse URI, e.g. `org.acme.project.subsystem`
4. For constants, use `ALL_CAPS.`

Answer (score 0):

Firebase may be finding the getter method `getDoctor_Id()` to be in conflict with the member variable `Doctor_Id`.

So, either change the case of your member variable so that the class looks like this, and is thus no longer in conflict:

```
public final class DoctorReg(){

    String doctor_Id;
    //The rest of your member variables here.

    public DoctorReg() {}

    public DoctorReg(String doctor_Id){
        this.doctor_Id = doctor_Id;
    }

    public String getDoctor_Id(){
        return doctor_Id;
    }

    //The rest of your getter methods below.

}
```

Or, try making your member variable `Doctor_Id` private. Since you don't specify an access modifier in your original class, it defaults to package-private.

Comment: let me try to do it

Comment: @RemmieSithole So you changed `String Doctor_Id` to `String doctor_Id`, and kept the getter method the same, with the capital variable name, and that did not work?

Comment: It is still prducing the same error...what about not recognising my method DocReg();  what is the error there

Comment: @RemmieSithole Where does it not recognize your method? Also, try putting your class back the way it was, and setting the variable to private.

Comment: at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source)...there

Comment: @RemmieSithole Alright, let's try this, and if it works, I'll update my answer. Change all of your member variable and method names to follow Java naming conventions with camelCase.